# Querying on optional parameters

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Suppose I have a user table with age and name columns. I would like to write a function to query this table, either selecting everything, or selecting based on age. Naively I might do

```
def query(age=''):
    query_args = ' WHERE {}'.format(age) if age else ''
    db.execute('SELECT * FROM users' + query_args)
```

obviously this is a horrible idea, but I'm not sure what the better way to deal with this situation is - it seems pretty ugly to write a separate query if age is passed as an argument or it's not, especially in more complicated examples where I might have multiple parameters to the query.

Comment: Note that solving this kind of problem with modern ORMs like SQLAlchemy would be quite easy.

Comment: @alecxe: One more software layer is not always the best solution. In many cases, including this one, it is just one more problem (big) to be dealt with.

Comment: Yes, we were using SQLalchemy originally but decided to just write our own interface. word up @ClodoaldoNeto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right in that building a query string is a terrible idea. This problem is not a driver one. It is just SQL:

```
query = """
    select *
    from users
    where
        (%(age)s is null or %(age)s = age)
        and
        (%(name)s is null or %(name)s = name)
"""
parameters = dict(name = None, age = 35)
cursor.execute(query, parameters)
```

If a certain parameter is passed as null it will not be filtered.